# Server 2012 Create Team of 2 Teams

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-teaming

I am wondering if there is a way to create a Team that consist of 2 Teams?

What I have going on is I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with 6 NICs going to our SAN switches.  I have 3 Teamed on one switch using LACP, and the other 3 going to another switch also using LACP.  The switches do not have Stacking capabilities so I cannot bond all 6 NICs together.  In addition everything is setup where the switches are in an Active/Standby architecture.  So what I am hoping to do is create an Active/Standby team of the 2 LACP teams so if the primary switch goes down the Team would detect that and switch to the Standby team.

Comment: What's the server? If it were HP you could use HP's own NIC teaming to bind each side then use Window's own to bind the two, don't know how to do it without - hate LACP links and tend to just use 10Gbps NICs to save the trouble! Good question though.

Comment: Dell PE R900, one NIC is Broadcom and the other is Intel.  That is a good thought process, I will try to use Broadcom to create a Broadcom team and then Intel for an Intel team and then see if Windows can use that.  I'll update this a couple of hours.